# How do I use a GET create path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, controller, get

How can I create a path that would take a user to GET create?

```
<%= link_to 'New Challenge', challenges_path(name: 'foo' ) %> #takes user to index
```

**challenges_controller**

```
  def create
    @challenge = Challenge.new(challenge_params)
    if params[:step] == '2'
      @challenge = current_user.challenges.build(challenge_params)
      @challenge.name = challenge_params[:name]
      if @challenge.name == 'foo'
        @challenge.category = 'habit'
      else
        @challenge.category = 'goal'
      end
      @challenge.save
      redirect_to @challenge
      respond_modal_with @challenge
    end
  end
```

**challenges/create.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@challenge)  do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :step, 2 %>
  etc..
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

First create a route for `GET` request to `challenges#create` in `routes.rb` as below:

`get 'create_challenge' => 'challenges#create'`

Now, you can use this to make get request to create path:

```
<%= link_to 'New Challenge', create_challenge_path(name: 'foo' ) %>
```

I don't know what is in `challenge_params` to make the `create` action work correctly you must pass the `challenge_params`.

If you need the params as: `{challenge: {name: 'foo'}}` you can do as below:

```
<%= link_to 'New Challenge', create_challenge_path(challenge: {name: 'foo'}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a create action should be triggered by a POST request (GET is used for reading as its name is suggesting).

Typical CRUD controller has the following mapping of actions to HTTP methods:

```
Create - POST;
Read - GET;
Update - PUT;
Delete - DELETE.
```

The routes from requests to controllers#actions are defined in the config/routes.rb file and will look like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post '/challenges', to: 'challenges#create', as: 'challenges_create'
end
```

Better read the Rails guides - [Action Controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html), [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), etc.